# How to Get Around Absolute Positioning - Causing Spans to Stack

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an animated text sentence on a responsive web site where there is changing text in the middle of a sentence. I am using spans so they are inline but "position: absolute" is making two of my spans stack on top of each other instead of being side by side. Without an absolute position my animated text runs all over the page. Not sure how to get around absolute and still have text that doesn't change + text that does + more text that stays the same. Would love any help anyone has to offer. Side detail: I can't use css keyframes because my boss requires iOS viewing.

Pic for reference with absolute: [with absolute positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRrsS.png)

```js
$(function() {

  var $slogans = $(".slogan").find("strong");
  var $holder = $("#holder");

  //settings
  var transitionTime = 0.4;
  var slogansDelayTime = 2;

  //internal
  var totalSlogans = $slogans.length;

  var oldSlogan = 0;
  var currentSlogan = -1;

  //initialize 
  switchSlogan();

  function switchSlogan() {

    oldSlogan = currentSlogan;

    if (currentSlogan < totalSlogans - 1) {
      currentSlogan++
    } else {
      currentSlogan = 0;
    }

    TweenLite.to($slogans.eq(oldSlogan), transitionTime, {
      alpha: 0,
      rotationX: 90
    });
    TweenLite.fromTo($slogans.eq(currentSlogan), transitionTime, {
      alpha: 0,
      rotationX: -90
    }, {
      top: 0,
      alpha: 1,
      rotationX: 0
    });

    TweenLite.delayedCall(slogansDelayTime, switchSlogan);
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #383838;
}

#holder {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.slogan {
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.slogan strong {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>

<div id="holder">
  <span style="font-size: 4em; text-transform: uppercase;"><b>DELIVERING    </b></span>
  <span style="color: #007cc3;" class="slogan"><strong>BUILDINGS </strong></span>
  <span style="color: #96c13c;" class="slogan"><strong>HOSPITALS</strong></span>
  <span style="color: #fdbb45;" class="slogan"><strong>LABORATORIES</strong></span>
  <span style="color: #8b0037;" class="slogan"><strong>PHARMACIES</strong></span>
  <span style="color: #f7941d;" class="slogan"><strong>PROGRAMS</strong></span>
  <span style="color: #004e7f;" class="slogan"><strong>CYLOTRONS</strong></span>
  <span style="color: #676764;" class="slogan"><strong>VIVARIUMS</strong></span><span style="position: relative; font-size: 4em; text-transform: uppercase;">That Work</span>

</div>
```

Comment: The example code you posted does not look like the image you included. Did you forget something?

Comment: Hi Marie, thanks for asking. The image is with the absolute positioning applied and the code is without it. So the animated words just run down the page. Make sense?

Comment: Gotcha, rather than (just) include an image you can also include the CSS that causes them to run together. It may help us to see how you are trying to apply it. I submitted an edit to your question to add the required libraries to run the snippet, too

Comment: Thanks. I did actually add the css too buy maybe I added it wrong...this is my first posted question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a container around the slogans and assign a height and width to it based on the largest slogan along with position relative, you can then use position absolute on the slogans inside of it for your desired effect as seen here:

```js
$(function() {

  var $slogans = $(".slogan").find("strong");
  var $holder = $("#holder");

  //settings
  var transitionTime = 0.4;
  var slogansDelayTime = 2;

  //internal
  var totalSlogans = $slogans.length;

  var oldSlogan = 0;
  var currentSlogan = -1;

  //set size for #slogans
  const slogans = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.slogan'), 0),
    sloganHeight = slogans[0].offsetHeight,
    sloganMaxWidth = Math.max(...slogans.map(t => t.offsetWidth))
    
  $('#slogans').css({ height: sloganHeight, width: sloganMaxWidth })
    
  

  //initialize
  switchSlogan();

  function switchSlogan() {

    oldSlogan = currentSlogan;

    if (currentSlogan < totalSlogans - 1) {
      currentSlogan++
    } else {
      currentSlogan = 0;
    }

    TweenLite.to($slogans.eq(oldSlogan), transitionTime, {
      alpha: 0,
      rotationX: 90
    });
    TweenLite.fromTo($slogans.eq(currentSlogan), transitionTime, {
      alpha: 0,
      rotationX: -90
    }, {
      top: 0,
      alpha: 1,
      rotationX: 0
    });

    TweenLite.delayedCall(slogansDelayTime, switchSlogan);
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #383838;
}

#holder {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#slogans {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.slogan {
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.slogan strong {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenLite.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js"></script>

<div id="holder">
  <span style="font-size: 4em; text-transform: uppercase;"><b>DELIVERING    </b></span>
  <div id="slogans">
    <span style="color: #007cc3;" class="slogan"><strong>BUILDINGS </strong></span>
    <span style="color: #96c13c;" class="slogan"><strong>HOSPITALS</strong></span>
    <span style="color: #fdbb45;" class="slogan"><strong>LABORATORIES</strong></span>
    <span style="color: #8b0037;" class="slogan"><strong>PHARMACIES</strong></span>
    <span style="color: #f7941d;" class="slogan"><strong>PROGRAMS</strong></span>
    <span style="color: #004e7f;" class="slogan"><strong>CYLOTRONS</strong></span>
    <span style="color: #676764;" class="slogan"><strong>VIVARIUMS</strong></span>
  </div>
  <span style="position: relative; font-size: 4em; text-transform: uppercase;">That Work</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

"Position:Absolute;" is proably the wrong approach altogether.  Instead of doing that, try hideing those spans with "display:none;" and use your swap function to change just your selected one to "display:inline;".

Another method is to save those spans as an array of strings in your JavaScript and swap out innerHTML inside of a single container span tag.